# How to install arm64 iso in QEMU on Ubuntu x86_64?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, arm64

I've tried to install the ubuntu-18.04.2-server-arm64.iso with libvirt Virtual Machine Manager to have an aarch64 (same as arm64) Ubuntu VM.

But it displays a message "Failed to setup UEFI for AArch64: did not find any UEFI binary path for arch 'aarch64'. Install options are limited."

So the option to install from an *.iso is not available.

What's the easy way for installing from an image?

Comment: using iso is your only option : https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_qemu?

Comment: @tatsu, there are UEFI and cdrom problems to overcome (http://www.redfelineninja.org.uk/daniel/2018/02/running-an-iso-installer-image-for-arm64-aarch64-using-qemu-and-kvm/). I'm trying to test it and make a script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like just the `qemu-efi` package was needed to be installed. The virt-manager GUI then can launch an install from the *.iso installer image.